# Position the play button in relation to the revealed content instead of the page

Tags: html, css, image, position, css-position

When the play image is clicked on it drops to the bottom, how do I prevent that?

To reproduce, click on it, and you will see it dropping down.

Click on it, scroll down and you will see the image has dropped.

How do I get the play image to stay in the same spot without dropping?

code https://jsfiddle.net/Lndptks3/2/

**Before clicking on image**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1MaG8DJ.png]

**After clicking on image**

[image]

You can see the play image falling down, how do I stop that from happening?

```js
(function iife() {
  "use strict";
  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }


  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".container");
    show(thewrap);
  }
  
  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacketa");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.curtain.slide {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 20s;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);
}

.panel-right {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100vw);
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* split the svg code below */

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
  transition: 20s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 20s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 20s ease;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.curtain.slide .split-wrap {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba(249, 6, 167, 0);
}

.jacketa {
  display: block !important;
}

.container {
  height: auto;
}

.curtain.slide .j1 {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

.curtain.slide .j2 {
  transform: translateX(100vw);
}


.j2 .j1{
  
    position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  
}

.container {
  width: 990px;
  height: 990px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #000000;
}

.container-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0 0 45px 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/jEMIULl.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="tcell">

      <div class="container hide">
        <div class="container-top">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-left"> </div>
      <div class="panel-right"> </div>

      <div class="split-wrap">
        <div class="j1">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="j2">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That thing seems to be in the centre of the page using margin auto. When the new content is added with `9999px` height, centre of the page changes. Either you have to reduce it's height or you have to position the play button in relation to the revealed content instead of the page

Comment: Can you provide an answer on how that would be done? Position the play button in relation to the revealed content instead of the page.

Comment: Can you show me how it would be written in the code?